# Overwrite self with extension property setter

Tags: kotlin

I want a Kotlin property that can replace the original value. For example:

```
var String.setString
    get() = "ignorethis"
    set(value) = this = value
```

(I'm actually using it on UBytes to add getters and setters for the upper and lower nibbles).

However, in my example above I get `Variable expected.` Is it possible to modify `this` with an extension property?

Comment: No, it's not possible. How would you expect `"abc".setString = "def"` to work? Or `("abc" + "def").setString = "xyz"`?

Comment: You can't do this; but I don't think it would be a good thing to do even if you could.  In this case, `String` is immutable, so it wouldn't make sense to add a property with a setter — and it would confuse me to see one called.  Better to have a simple extension method, as callers will _expect_ that to return a separate object.  (I think you can still call it something like `setUpperNibble()`.)

Comment: If you have limited amount of variables that require this behavior, you can change them into delegated properties and have your custom delegate implementation replace internal value

Answer (score 0):

`String` is immutable, and you can only do that on mutable types like this:

````
fun main() {
    val x = mutableListOf("old")
    x.setString = mutableListOf("New Pro Max Extra Large Plus")
    println(x)
}

var <T> MutableList<T>.setString
    get() = this
    set(value) = value.forEachIndexed { idx, it -> this[idx] = it } ```
````